# CodeIgniter encoding and decoding arguments in url

Tags: codeigniter, decode, encode

Ok i wanna encode arguments which i send to controler and function in this case number 1 i wanna use url_decode and encode function is it possible to do?

view page

```
<a href="<?= site_url('home/page/1'); ?>"> Create </a>
```

controler

```
 public function page($selfi){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('photos');
        $this->db->join('bridge', 'bridge.photos_id = photos.id');
        $this->db->where('bridge.tags_id',$selfi);
        $data['query'] = $this->db->get();

        $this->load->view('gallery_view',$data);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that you're trying to accomplish. What type of arguments do you want to pass to the controller and in what context would you use them?

Comment: Ok i pass number 1 in cotroler and on that number i making mysql query where i get results

Comment: any answers? to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're trying to do it this way, but here's how:

```
<a href="<?=site_url('home/page/'.url_encode('1')); ?>"> Create </a>
```

And on the controller side:

```
public function page($selfi){
    $selfi = url_decode($selfi);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('photos');
    $this->db->join('bridge', 'bridge.photos_id = photos.id');
    $this->db->where('bridge.tags_id',$selfi);
    $data['query'] = $this->db->get();
    $this->load->view('gallery_view',$data);
}
```